# How to turn an ordinary flexbox nav into a responsive hamburger mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I am trying to understand how to properly design and code a responsive navigation.

I've started with a list with `display:flexbox` and `flex-direction: column` applied.

I have a logo on top and menu items below. Simple.

In my media query section I apply `flex-direction: row;` and `justify-content: flex-end;` to the list if the viewport is at least `82em`. The `nav` turns into a row.

So far so good. What I would like to achieve is a "hamburger menu". Logo on the left, hamburger icon on the right. No fancy animations, no jquery, and no javascript (if it's possible to show/hide menu without using JS). If I click/touch an menu item I'd like the menu to fold/disappear.

I don't understand how can I get the hamburger icon positioned. If the logo is a list element I also don't understand how to keep it visible and hide the rest of the links if menu I hide/fold it.

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  align-self: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
}

.brand a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
}

.brand h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline;
}

@media (max-width: 81em) {
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav a {
    padding: 0.4em 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 81em) {
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .brand {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  nav a {
    padding: 0.6rem;
  }
  nav ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 2.5rem;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="brand">
      <a href="#">
        <h1>NAME</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ITEM 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZLaRx

Comment: If you don't want to use js then you would need to use something like a checkbox or radio and have your menu nested correctly (ie if the items are a sub menu of the heading, then it should be in a nested ul within the heading li) - here is an example of a burger menu using a checkbox: https://codepen.io/elgreg/pen/rGgfF

Comment: I'm having a look at this, but it's going to take quite a bit of work, try googling something like "how to make a hamburger menu only using CSS" as this is the type of thing people right blogs about - but it is quite a big job using hidden div's, media queries and :target elements

Comment: @Pete that's really cool! thanks for sharing - defintinely an effective "no-frills" solution to a simple hamburger nav

Comment: I don't really mind using a bit of JS. I was just curious if it's possible to do it pure CSS.

Comment: It is possible using only CSS. Please check this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzbKaL